# how to call to javascript function in the same file using php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have php file called "PhpCallJavascript".

I try to call to function `CreateSVG()` from php code.

it is not working should I need here ajax?

or somthing else?

thx for any help.

the php file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'CreateSVG();', '</script>'; ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    function CreateSVG(){
            var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
                alert(xmlns);
            }
});     
</script>
```

Comment: And why would you need to echo the call to the function and not the function itself ?

Comment: if you know to slove it without  echo please show me becose I don't know :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have two main problems.

First: **Functions are not hoisted between script elements**

If you call a function inline (without waiting for a suitable event), then the function you call must either be declared in the *same* script element or an *earlier* one.

Second: **Functions declared inside other functions are scoped to that function**

Since you have declared `CreateSVG` inside an anonymous function (which you then pass to `ready()`), you cannot access `CreateSVG` from outside that anonymous function.

A fixed version of the code would be:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function CreateSVG(){
            var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            alert(xmlns);
    }
    CreateSVG();
</script>
```

Comment: did the code should be like this: `<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'CreateSVG();', '</script>'; ?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function CreateSVG(){
            var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
                alert(xmlns);
            }
    }

    CreateSVG();
</script>` becose it stil not working.. thanks

Comment: No. The code should appear as I wrote it in my answer. You've added (at least) an additional script element and a `}` to what I wrote.

Comment: Yes You right..  but I need to cheack if some condition in php exist ,if it exist I need to call it from php code. not from javascript to javascript.

Comment: So make that check, and output the code I wrote above if it passes (without the extra script and the extra `}`).

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript">CreateSVG();</script>'; ?>
```

Try this?

EDIT-

Apologies, read the way it was written wrong. Was assuming he had a syntax error when the function itself just needed to be moved.

Comment: That will output the same code as the version in the original question. It doesn't change anything sent to the client.

Comment: Apologies, read the way it was written wrong. Was assuming he had a syntax error when the function [call] itself just needed to be moved.